# angularJS $http request 'how to sync'

Tags: angularjs

I think you find this question thousands of times...but I can't really understand the way to solve.

I have a `$http` request inside a `Service`...

```
app.service('getData', function ($http) {

this.getDataList = function () {
 $http.get('../content/catalog/data.json')
         .success(function(response) {
          return response;  
    })      
};
```

I call it from the `app.run`

```
    app.run(function (getData) {
      list=getData.getDataList()
    })
```

If I log the `list` variable is undefined

What is the way to sync them?

Thank you for the help!!!!

Comment: If something does not sync itself properly you can use $scope.$apply() but only if really needed

Comment: The answers talking about promises didn't realize you are not returning $http.get, return this and use it in your scope as-is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're treating the call as if it were synchronous, where as its an Async call, so when you say `return response;` that line executes when the call hasn't finished yet and naturally you get undefined, use a callback instead or return a promise:

```
this.getDataList = function (callback) {
 $http.get('../content/catalog/data.json')
         .success(function(response) {
          callback(response);
    })      
};
```

Usage:

```
getData.getDataList(function(data){
 var list=data;
 console.log(data);
});
```

EDIT:
Regarding promises, the idea is very simple, whenever you have an async operation that you expect will not be completed immediately, i.e. ajax calls, you can use a promise returned by the method making that async operation in order to find out when the task has finished.

For example `$http` returns a promise by default, so you can change your code to make use of that promise by simply returning the `$http` call itself:

```
this.getDataList = function () {
   return $http.get('../content/catalog/data.json');
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
getDataList().then(function(successData){
   var list=successData;
},function(errorResponse){
   alert("something terrible has happened!");
})
```

The promise returned by `$http` takes 2 callbacks, the first for a successful call and the second is for errors.

Nowadays I mostly just pass callbacks in to the function making the async call, saves me from having to write `then()`.

Comment: Thank You.....it works...but i still have to understand how to use promise...if you have a good link...=)

Comment: @icchio - Promises have a little bit of a learning curve with the syntax and concept, but very rewarding in the long term.

Answer (score 0):

list is undefined because you forgot to return $http.get in this.getDataList()

By the way, $http will return a **promise** (an object with then and finally methods), which you can directly use in ng-bind for instance.

Comment: what did you mean `directly use in ng-bind`? the promise?

Comment: You can use promises in ng-bind expressions if you assign list to a $scope (but here you don't have a controller so that won't be possible).

Comment: the examples are in the Angular doc about ng-bind, $watch which used by bind works with functions as well as objects.

Answer (score -1):

Use `promises` instead.

JavaScript uses promises for async(deferred) operations. These promises are based on callbacks(I promise to run your callback when I'm done).

`getDataList` does a http.get behind the scenes and doesn't block the code. It simply returns a promise object.
You can add callbacks to the promise object that will happen when the async operation finishes.

```
app.service('getData', function ($http) {    
    this.getDataList = function () {
         return $http.get('../content/catalog/data.json');
    }; 
});

app.run(function (getData) {
   getData.getDataList().then(function(res){
      list = res
   });
});
```

Comment: Please add an explanation what exactly the OP was doing wrong (your answer is correct).

Comment: This answer is incorrect, list will be undefined until the answer comes back, you should do list = getData.getDataList(), and then use either promise wrappers, treat it directly as a promise or bind it in a relevant html attribute using watchers.

Comment: The answer is correct. list will have a value since getDataList returns a promise and that promise updates the list with a callback. Doing list = getData.getDataList() will assign list with a promise and not with it's correct value.
BTW, the selected answer(by Mohammad) will work, but it's a poor design to send your callbacks as params. That's exactly what promises came to solve.